# Origin of the Name 'Chernoff Sequence'

Tags: number-theory, math-history

I discovered the Chernoff Sequence, [$A006939$](https://oeis.org/A006939) while thinking about recreating the divisibility of $12$ and $360$. I was actually surprised to see that it already existed, and it caught my attention. Unfortunately, google seems entirely in the dark, and I can't figure out what Herman Chernoff had to do with it at all, or really what the purpose of the sequence is.

Any sort of origin would be helpful.

Comment: It might be a different Chernoff (its not exactly an uncommon soviet block last name) or have nothing to do with him.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Chernoff sequence was contributed by Paul Chernoff, California, to the book authored by C. Pickover: Mazes for the Mind, St. Martin's Press, NY, 1992, p. 351, as cited in the OEIS link in your post. This individual may be Emeritus Professor Paul R. Chernoff of UC Berkeley. His home page is located at http://math.berkeley.edu/people/faculty/paul-r-chernoff.